# Limit number of outgoing calls to RESTful service

Tags: java, spring, rest, service

I am working on a project, and the application will make calls to a REST API. The partner defined that there should be no more than 40 calls per second to the API. As I have never worked on such a limitation before, I was wondering which is the best way to handle this. The project language is Java and the application is implemented as Spring microservice. 
Any opinion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it really your app's responsibility to throttle?  What should be the behavior if the upstream process invokes > than the threshold?  Does the architecture include a gateway (so that the gateway can control the throttle)?

Comment: The only condition is no more than 40 requests to be sent to this API. I can use a gateway, but i do not know which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [cron expressions](https://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions)
It will allow you a lot of cases of scheduling.

For managing data it'll be preferred a Queue or [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Comment: Thank you, but apart from scheduling i also need queueing. If i have to send 200 requests per second, where i could queue the others?

Answer (score 0):

I would say per second checking hit count would be little bit aggressive. So lets keep our time to 5 seconds and max 200 API calls. You can have a utility component which tells to make call or not based on past calls count.

```
@Component
public class HitLimit {

    private AtomicInteger hitCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void scheduleClean() {
        hitCount.set(0);
    }

    public boolean canMakeCall() {
        return hitCount.incrementAndGet() < 200;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but if i have to send 200 requests per second, where i could queue the others?

Comment: @IvajloIliev I thought you said you need to limit. We can't queue user request and do when limit not exists, it will make system complex lot of request connection open. If this call can happen async, you need to implement a queue task system.